# ViewModel com Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, injeção-de-dependência

Estou fazendo uma logica em meu app para apresentar a appBar do mesmo apenas quando eu precisar que ala apareça ou nao.

Para isso, fiz o seguinte ViewModel: StateAppViewModel

````
@HiltViewModel
class StateAppViewModel @Inject constructor(
) : ViewModel() {

    val components: LiveData<VisualComponents> get() = _components

    private var _components: MutableLiveData<VisualComponents> =
        MutableLiveData<VisualComponents>().also {
            it.value = hasComponents
        }

    var hasComponents: VisualComponents = VisualComponents()
        set(value) {
            field = value
            _components.value = value
        }
}

class VisualComponents(
    val appBar: Boolean = false
) ´´´

Na classe que quero que o appBar aparece, eu faço:
 ```stateAppViewModel.hasComponents = VisualComponents(true)´´´

E na MainActivity verifico:


    controller.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            title = destination.label
            viewModel.components.observe(this, {
                it?.let { hasComponents ->
                    if (hasComponents.appBar) {
                        supportActionBar?.show()
                    } else {
                        supportActionBar?.hide()
                    }
                }
            })
        }

Acredito que esteja fazendo algo errado, pois o viewModel não é injetado pelo Hilt.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?
````

Answer (score 0):

O Hilt nunca injeta `ViewModels` (dê uma olhada em https://dagger.dev/hilt/view-model.html para mais informações). Você precisa inicializar o seu `ViewModel` na MainActivity pra poder usar ele. Eu sugiro o seguinte código pra isso:

```
private val viewModel by viewModels<StateAppViewModel>()
```

Declare a variável acima como variável de instância da sua Activity. Se o Android Studio não tiver encontrando o método `viewModels`, inclua a dependência `"androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.2"` no seu `app/build.gradle`.

Comment: Massa, muito obrigado